# Collecting postal adresses from webpages?

Tags: web-scraping, named-entity-recognition

I'm looking for a special program that able to collect postal adresses from web pages, not only from one pages, all pages from specific area.

I mean I want to find&collect all the enterprises in london. For example i would like to find the all hairdressers postal adresses in London. I just type hairdresser London and the program will collect me the data in tables like this style: url, postal adress

www.hairdresserlondon1.com, 83 Berwick Street, London, United Kingdom
www.hairdresserlondon2.com, 12 Getwick Street, London, United Kingdom

and so on...

Is there any idea which program is good for this task? What's the name of this kind of method?

Comment: it's called data scraping and is somewhat frowned upon

Comment: ok thanks, and what is the easy to use and perfect program for it? i tried to find but the are so complicated...

Comment: why don't you use google map api to find all hairdressers in london? I'm pretty sure they have a way of doing that kind of requests. Plus, you don't have to write a shady program to scrape data from other sites.

Comment: And can i download the data from map in KML format? if yes it's ok for me!